# "rhc cartridges" not showing cartridge added with oo-admin-cartridge

Tags: openshift-origin

I installed a cartridge with "oo-admin-cartridge -a install -s /path/to/cartridge". It shows up in "oo-admin-cartridge -a list", however it doesn't show up in "rhc cartridges". This is on release 4 of the Origin VM. On release 3, I don't have any problems installing additional cartridges.

I know similar questions have been asked before, like [Deploying Custom Cartridges on Openshift Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195318/deploying-custom-cartridges-on-openshift-origin), but none of my attempts at clearing the cache seem to help. I've tried:

- oo-admin-broker-cache --console --clear
- cd /var/www/openshift/broker && scl enable ruby193 "bundle exec rake tmp:clear"
- rm -rf /var/www/openshift/broker/tmp/cache/*
- service openshift-broker restart
- service ruby193-mcollective restart
- rebooting

I also see that my cartridge was added to /var/lib/openshift/.cartridge_repository.

Why isn't rhc getting the most recent list of cartridges? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the following command, which I can't find anywhere in the documentation:

oo-admin-ctl-cartridge --activate -c import-node --obsolete