# Missing jboss tomcat cartridge

Tags: tomcat, jboss, openshift-origin

I installed openshift origin using oo-install. However it was missing tomcat and jboss cartridges. I ran  yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap.noarch ..

```
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (openshift-origin)
           Requires: jbossas-domain
Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (openshift-origin)
           Requires: jbossas-jbossweb-native
Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (openshift-origin)
           Requires: jbossas-core
Error: Package: openshift-origin-cartridge-jbosseap-2.19.1.1-1.el6.noarch (openshift-origin)
           Requires: jbossas-welcome-content-eap
```

Is there a way to install jboss and tomcat cartridges outside yum?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The required RPMs are not in the current Openshift repository, but in the old one so you can install them manually.

I did it as mentioned in following thread: https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshift-archives/dev/2014-July/msg00224.html

```
yum install https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/origin-server/release/3/rhel-6/dependencies/x86_64/maven3-3.0.3-4.noarch.rpm 
yum install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-3/noarch/tomcat6-6.0.39-1.noarch.rpm 
yum install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-3/noarch/tomcat7-7.0.50-1.noarch.rpm 
yum install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/getup-mirror/getup-openshift-origin-release-3/noarch/jboss-as7-7.1.1.Final-1.noarch.rpm
yum install openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews
```

That's how it works with Tomcat, i think it should also work with JBoss.

Comment: Thanks. That did help. But I am still not able to see the option in the console

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569715/rhc-cartridges-not-showing-cartridge-added-with-oo-admin-cartridge (unfortunately this is not in the official documentation)